# Rake task takes significantly longer on Heroku than locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake-task

I have a rake task that takes about 90 seconds locally. It loops through objects and creates a large PG insert SQL, then executes it at the end.

On Heroku `heroku run rake my_task` it takes about 1.5 hrs (same data as local). I've been researching Heroku and "One-Off Dynos" but I can't find much info on why it would take so long, other than the fact that my app is on the Heroku free plan with only one web dyno and 0 workers.

Its not the insert that takes long, it's the loop beforehand (loop does not have DB calls).

DB is PG Hobby-Basic.
Rails 4.2
Ruby 1.9.3p374

Comment: are you working on approximately the same size of db records?

Comment: @jvnill yes the DB is cloned locally, same data.

Comment: Can you: show the code for the rake task; give us an idea on how many objects are generated and rows inserted; and perhaps an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of the query locally? Note that if you're doing a lot of work in Postgres on the free/hobby plan that there's an extremely minimal cache available for Postgres to work in, which can impact performance.

Comment: @elithrar I can't post the code right now, but it makes an initial call to the DB to grab about 100K items, then it loops through the items and creates SQL insert strings. This is the part that is quick locally, and slow on heroku. It doesn't make any DB calls. At the end, it makes one insert statement. I'm not concerned about that part. The task prints progress, and it seems to freeze every few thousand loops.

Comment: Grabbing a set of 100K items and then iterating through them in Ruby isn't going to be hugely fast on a small dyno. There should be no surprise that it's quick locally: most devs have home machines much faster than even some of the larger Amazon EC2 instances. Further, those 100k items are likely coming via disk IO on the hobby tier, which is going to add to the "slowness".

Comment: @elithrar can I upgrade my dynos to run this task once? Its a migration. If so, what plan/dynos do you recommend? Web vs Workers? Qty?

Comment: Take a look here - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#one-off-dyno-type - if you're using a `standard-1X` dyno or bigger for your web process, you can run one-off tasks on faster dynos. Note that your DB might still be a bottleneck. Test with a more performant dyno and see if it makes a difference (it's hard to know without seeing numbers!) :)

Comment: @elithrar ok thanks. I'll do some experimenting.

Comment: @elithrar Switching to Performance dynos and running `heroku run --size=performance rake my_task` worked much quicker. Put your comment in an answer and I'll mark it resolved, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a standard-1X dyno or bigger for your web process, you can run one-off tasks on faster dynos, as sorting ~100k objects in Ruby on a free/hobby dyno is likely to stretch it.

This article covers the basics - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#one-off-dyno-type for setting the dyno size for a one-off dyno.